# Count without grouping on every column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to write a query that gives me everyone who has a a curriculum from a given list, what curriculum they have, and a column that has how many total people have that particular curriculum. However, if I use the count feature then I have to group by each column which then gives a count for how many records in the academic table that person has for that curriculum. Is there a way for me to only count the number of people that have a particular curriculum. Below is a table with an example of what I would want the results to look like.

| First_Name | Last_Name | People_id | Curriculum | Curriculum_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Olivia | Scotts | 123456 | ACC | 2 |
| Elijah | Miller | 234567 | ACC | 2 |
| Carter | Wilson | 345678 | BUS | 1 |
| Hannah | Walker | 456789 | ENG | 3 |
| Camila | Timber | 567890 | ENG | 3 |
| Annett | Ferron | 678901 | ENG | 3 |

The query below is what I what I originally tried. I knew it wouldn't work, but I don't know what to do in order to find the information without like pasting it into excel or something.

```
select distinct
    people.first_name,
    people.last_name,
    academic.people_id,
    academic.CURRICULUM,
    count(academic.curriculum) Curriculum_Count
from academic   
join people on people.people_id = academic.people_id
where
    academic.curriculum in (
'bus',
'acc',
'eng'
)
group by academic.curriculum
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve the desired result, you need to use a subquery to count the number of people for each curriculum separately. Here's an example query that should work:

```
SELECT p.first_name, p.last_name, a.people_id, a.curriculum, c.curriculum_count
FROM academic a
JOIN people p ON p.people_id = a.people_id
JOIN (
  SELECT curriculum, COUNT(DISTINCT people_id) AS curriculum_count
  FROM academic
  WHERE curriculum IN ('BUS', 'ACC', 'ENG')
  GROUP BY curriculum
) c ON a.curriculum = c.curriculum
WHERE a.curriculum IN ('BUS', 'ACC', 'ENG')
```

The subquery counts the number of distinct people for each curriculum that appears in the academic table. The main query then joins this subquery on the curriculum column to add the curriculum_count column to the results.

Note that you still need to filter by the three specific curriculums in the subquery and the main query, otherwise you would get curriculum counts for all curriculums in the academic table.

Comment: @Neill probably doesn't perform as well as the window function version though.

Answer (score 0):

You want a windowed count e.g.

```
select
    p.First_Name
    , p.Last_Name
    , a.People_Id
    , a.Curriculum
    , count(*) over (partition by a.Curriculum) Curriculum_Count
from academic a
join people p on p.People_Id = a.People_Id
where a.Curriculum in (
    'bus',
    'acc',
    'eng'
);
```

Note the table aliases for improved readability.

Also consistent casing and naming makes queries easier to read.